# Why does the order of data points in the data set affect statistical test?

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am comparing two non-normal distributions of continuous variables of a repeated-measures design (the dependent variables are reaction-times in miliseconds when reading two types of words). Therefore, I am using a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test, but the same phenomenon happens if I run a t-test.

If I randomly re-sort one of the distributions being compared, the test (Z or t) and p-value change.

For instance:
Variable1 (n=723 of which 176 are missing data/outliers): 
546, 345, 987, 1023, ...

Variable2 (N = 723 of which 102 are missing data/outliers): 
567, 435, 230, 765, ...

If I randomly sort the order of the data of Variable2 so it is ordered differently, for instance:
Variable2_random: 765, 567, 435, 230, ...

I get different Z/t scores and p-values when doing the test for Variable1 vs. Variable2 than for Variable1 vs Variable2_random.

Why is this? (Specifically for the Wilcoxon signed test).

If the order of data points matters for this test, in what order should I be placing the data in the data set?

Answer (score 3):

Repeat measures are paired. If the pairing (i.e., rank order) is randomized, then paired difference data tests like [Wilcoxon signed rank testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) are invalid. This is because the order of ranking is used to find a correlation, and if the order is mixed up, the correlation is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you! However, I still don´t know in which order to insert the responses in the data set.

Comment: Each subject read words from two conditions in a random order. Therefore, each data point isn´t exactly paired to another data point from the other condition. Furthermore, both variables have different amount of missing data.

Comment: Are you sorting responses to each word type for each subject? Is each word type tested more than once for each subject?

Comment: Answer to first question: I am not inserting responses in my data set in the order they were recorded, but grouping them into their respective condition. Second question: yes. Subjects read 24 different words from condition 1 and 24 different words from condition 2 in random order (e.g., cond2 cond1 1 2 2 1 2 NA 2...), the same random order for all participants. Should I list the final data set in the order the responses were recorded (participant by participant) or can I not use Wilcoxon for this comparison?

Comment: What is your hypothesis?

Comment: My hypothesis is that condition 1 should produce larger reaction times than condition 2.

Comment: So, the major determinants are the subjects, who can be presumed to have different reactions times, and the conditions which are somewhat variable for each individual. So, if you first take the median value of conditions 1 and 2 for each individual, and then use these condition medians as paired values, per individual, and then do Wilcoxon signed-rank testing on individual pairings, you will get a preliminary answer for you hypothesis. There are other questions that need answering, but, that would be one way to start the analysis.

Comment: Carl, thank you SO much for your help. I understood that I should make the following list. Cond1: [Median of answers of subject1, median of answers of subject2, etc.], cond2: [median of answers of subject1, median of answers of subject2, etc.]. I will verify I'm doing the right thing before trying to publish. Thanks again! It was my first time using this forum, and I am really satisfied.